# how to run multiple text file in matlab and get separate output file?

Tags: matlab

Hi I am having multiple text file name `ABR1.txt,ABR2.txt,....ABR1000.txt`
I have wrote down matlab code for distance calculation. So I want that all the file present in the current folder should run in this code and provide separate output file. So I am trying but only one `ABR1.txt` is giving output. Please check it and let me know what i can do?

```
clc
clear all

for n=1:2
        filename = ['ABR', int2str(n), '.txt'];
        Pop=load(filename);


[m n] = size(Pop);
n = m;
Dist = zeros(m, n);
for i = 1 : m
  for j = 1 : n
      Dist(i, j) = sqrt((Pop(i, 1) - Pop(j, 1)) ^ 2 + ...
                        (Pop(i, 2) - Pop(j, 2)) ^ 2);
  end
end
Dist
q=(1-(3/8)*Dist)

filename = ['ABRa', int2str(n), '.txt'];
save(filename, 'q', '-ascii');
end
```

Comment: If you have 1000 files why are you not running the loop 1000 times..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable "n" both as your loop/file counter, and as the size of the matrix you read. I don't know what the data you're loading looks like, but if "n" ends up at a value of 1, then you'll only ever write the file name with "1" in it. You may actually be writing it twice, but both times have the same file name.

I would start by changing your for loop to use some other variable name:

```
for iFile = 1:2
```

Then also change it in the file name:

```
filename = ['ABRa', int2str(iFile), '.txt'];
```

Also, if you're really trying to read 1000 files, you should run your loop 1000 times, not twice:

```
for iFile = 1:1000
```